# How to add loop and queue command to discord js music bot

Tags: discord.js

How to add loop and queue commands to this discord js music bot?
I followed a guide and made a simple music bot with Discord js. It works but I could'nt find out how to add a loop and queue command to this bot. Also whenever I add songs to the queue it lags for a second. If anybody knows anything about that then some info would be nice.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { prefix, token } = require("./config.json");
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");
const yts = require("yt-search");
const client = new Discord.Client();

const queue = new Map();


client.on("message", async message => {
  
  const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);

  if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}play`)) {
    execute(message, serverQueue);
    return;
  } 
  
  if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}skip`)) {
    skip(message, serverQueue);
    return;
  } 
  if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}stop`)) {
    stop(message, serverQueue);
    return;
  }
  
});

async function execute(message, serverQueue) {
  const args = message.content.split(" ");

  const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
  if (!voiceChannel)
    return message.channel.send(
      "You need to be in a voice channel to play music!"
    );
  const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
  if (!permissions.has("CONNECT") || !permissions.has("SPEAK")) {
    return message.channel.send(
      "I need the permissions to join and speak in your voice channel!"
    );
  }

 let song;
 if (ytdl.validateURL(args[1])) {
  const songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(args[1]);
  song = {
    title: songInfo.title,
    url: songInfo.video_url
  };
 } else {
  const {videos} = await yts(args.slice(1).join(" "));
  if (!videos.length) return message.channel.send("No songs were found!");
  song = {
    title: videos[0].title,
    url: videos[0].url
  };
 }


  if (!serverQueue) {
    const queueContruct = {
      textChannel: message.channel,
      voiceChannel: voiceChannel,
      connection: null,
      songs: [],
      volume: 7,
      playing: true,
      
    };

    queue.set(message.guild.id, queueContruct);

    queueContruct.songs.push(song);

    try {
      var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
      queueContruct.connection = connection;
      play(message.guild, queueContruct.songs[0]);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      queue.delete(message.guild.id);
      return message.channel.send(err);
    }
  } else {
    serverQueue.songs.push(song);
    return message.channel.send(`${song.title} has been added to the queue!`);
  }
}

function play(guild, song) {
  const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);
  if (!song) {
    serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
    queue.delete(guild.id);
    return;
  }

const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection
    .play(ytdl(song.url))
    .on("finish", () => {
      serverQueue.songs.shift();
      play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
    })
    .on("error", error => console.error(error));
  dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);
  serverQueue.textChannel.send(`Start playing: **${song.title}**`);
}


function skip(message, serverQueue) {
  if (!message.member.voice.channel)
    return message.channel.send(
      "You have to be in a voice channel to stop the music!"
    );
  if (!serverQueue)
    return message.channel.send("There is no song that I could skip!");
  serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

function stop(message, serverQueue) {
  if (!message.member.voice.channel)
    return message.channel.send(
      "You have to be in a voice channel to stop the music!"
    );
    
  if (!serverQueue)
    return message.channel.send("There is no song that I could stop!");
    
  serverQueue.songs = [];
  serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}





client.login(token);
```

Comment: You're pretty much asking us to do your bot project for you. Here's some potential solutions on how you could solve it, but you're really asking too much of Stack Overflow on just spoon-feeding the code.

A) Use an Array with objects, where each object has a YouTube ID and a Loop boolean [{id:"abc123", loop: true}]. B) Set a global loop variable, and return to the start of the array of IDs at the end of the queue if loop is true

Answer (score 1):

You can use Map instead of array. Save all your looped music informations (such as Youtube URL, id and etc.). Then write a function to play saved music at the of the current song.